# Azure AD B2C authenticate with API key

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-active-directory

I'm investigating Azure AD B2C as a possible auth service, which we want to use for user management and authentication. We have a web application, Web API which we can easily integrate with AAD B2C and migrate our current authentication and user management.

However, I did not find any solution how to authenticate mobile applications and integrate it with azuere ad b2c. Our mobile app communicates also with web api but it does not need any user login. These applications are tied to a tenant and every mobile app instance has an API key that is used to authenticate the mobile app on the backend.

Is it possible with azure ad b2c to achieve that kind of authentication, that we will generate API keys for our mobile apps and will use the same ad in azure like the normal users? Is possible with azure ad b2c or we should use another azure service?

What are the best practices in this area? It is similar to the backend to backend communication where API keys are used. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal way for such a scenario would be to use the client credentials flow, where you use your ClientID + ClientSecret for a silent login in order to get a non-personalized AccessToken.
Although it seems that this type of flow is currently not supported by AD B2C. Have a look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/application-types#current-limitations

As an alternative, that page is refering to the client credentials flow of the Microsoft Identity Platform (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow).
I guess it now depends on the detailed requirements of your application whether it could be an option for you to use.

Comment: Client credentials flow means that an application has a client id + client secret which is basically username + password. We want to identify applications based on identity does it make sense to generate client id+ secret for every app instance? We have to manage also multitenancy so we have to identify from request to which tenant the given application belongs and simultaneously know which application made the request.

Comment: Yes, it could be considered as username + password - but the "user" is then kind of technical user of the application. So you have only one set of credentails for your application definition. And all running instances of the applications use it. It's application credentials, not user credentials. When you want to distinguish different tenants you can think about having one application definition per tenant (separate ClientIDs) and then select the correct one for app auth. But whats best here depends on further details.